# files per directory in a single line

Tags: find, ls

I have following directories:

```
Sample1 
Sample2
```

Each of it contains multiple subfolders like

```
Sample1/R1/
Sample1/R2/
Sample1/R3/
Sample2/R1/
Sample2/R2/
Sample2/R3/
```

Which further contains the files:

```
Sample1/R1/file1
Sample1/R2/file1
Sample1/R3/file1
Sample2/R1/file1
Sample2/R2/file1
Sample2/R3/file1
```

I want a list like:

```
Sample1/R1/file1 Sample1/R2/file1 Sample1/R3/file1
Sample2/R1/file1 Sample2/R2/file1 Sample2/R3/file1
```

I tried 'ls;, 'find' but no luck.

Please can someone help?

May thanks in advance.

Comment: ls `*/*/*` ? (star slash star slash star) ls `Sample?/R?/file1` ?

Comment: `ls */*/* | xargs -n3` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f | awk -F / '{a[$2]=a[$2] " " $0}; END {for(b in a){print a[b]}}'
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for POSIXification.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
for d (Sample*) print -r $d/*/*
```

Or to print all non-directory files:

```
for d (Sample*) print -r $d/**/*(^/)
```

(note that if there are file names that contain newline characters, that won't be on one line).

Or with any Bourne-like shell:

```
for d in Sample*; do
  find "$d" ! -type d | paste -sd ' ' -
done
```